# Loop through files in directory, count number of lines in each, copy to new filename if less than 500 lines

Tags: python

New to python. I have a directory with >1000 text files. Each file has anywhere between 1 and 1000 lines in it. I want to write a simple python script that opens and reads each file in the directory, counts the number of lines, and only copies the file if it is less than or equal to 500 lines. I would like the copy to preserve the original file name, but add an _c before the extension (ie foo.txt is copied to foo_c.txt only if foo.txt had <= 500 lines in it). Searching around it seems I'll need to use glob and shutil, but can't seem to get it name my output properly:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import shutil

list_of_files = glob.glob('./path/to/directory/*.txt') 

for fileName in list_of_files:
       with open(fileName) as i:
               count = sum(1 for _ in i)
               if count <= 500:
                       shutil.copyfile(fileName, fileName + "_c")
                       print("copying " + fileName)
               else:
                       pass
```

It runs on a test set of data, however it names the output *.txt_c instead of *_c.txt. So the problem is the fileName variable includes the extension. Is there any way to insert the _c modification before the extension? Thanks.

Comment: you don't need `else: pass` - it is useless.

Comment: Consider using an external utility to count the number of lines in each file as that will be much faster.  "wc -l" will return the number of lines in a file.

Comment: you have to remove `.txt`  (`filename[:-4]`) and then add `_c.txt`. Or `filename.replace('.txt', '_c.txt')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to separate the extension from the rest of the filename:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import shutil

list_of_files = glob.glob('./path/to/directory/*.txt') 

for fileName in list_of_files:
    with open(fileName) as i:
        count = sum(1 for _ in i)
        if count <= 500:
            root, ext = os.path.splitext(fileName)
            shutil.copyfile(fileName, root + "_c" + ext)
            print("copying " + fileName)
```

and you can use `"_c".join` if you are feeling sassy:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import shutil

list_of_files = glob.glob('./path/to/directory/*.txt') 

for fileName in list_of_files:
    with open(fileName) as i:
        count = sum(1 for _ in i)
        if count <= 500:
            splitName = os.path.splitext(fileName)
            shutil.copyfile(fileName, "_c".join(splitName))
            print("copying " + fileName)
```